# Show that the roots of the equation $(p^4 + q^4)x^2 + 4pqrs x + r^4 + s^4 = 0$ can not be different if real

Tags: algebra-precalculus

After a little bit of simplification of the discriminant, which must be equal to $0$ in this case, i derived the following

$$2pqrs = \sqrt{(p^4+q^4)(s^4+r^4)}$$

I believe it is now essential to prove that they are the same so that they cancel out to give me 0, thus proving that the roots of the following can't be difference if real, making the solution

$$-\frac{2pqrs}{p^4 + q^4}$$

using $-\frac{b}{2a}$

How do i do that? A friend of mine said he did it using the relations between arithmetic and geometric mean, however i am not familiar with that concept and would like an explanation for that and any other approaches to a solution if possible.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the general quadratic
$ax^2+bx+c=0$,
the roots are
$\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{D}}{2a}$,
where
$D = b^2-4ac$.

There are two real roots if
$D > 0$,
one repeated real root
if $D = 0$,
and two complex roots
if $D < 0$.

For your case,

$\begin{array}\\
D 
&= (4pqrs)^2-4(p^4+q^4)(r^4+s^4)\\
&=16p^2q^2r^2s^2-4(p^4r^4+p^4s^4+q^4r^4+q^4s^4)\\
&=-4(p^4r^4+p^4s^4+q^4r^4+q^4s^4-4p^2q^2r^2s^2)\\
&=-4(p^4r^4+q^4s^4-2p^2q^2r^2s^2+p^4s^4+q^4r^4-2p^2q^2r^2s^2)\\
&=-4((p^2r^2-q^2s^2)^2+(p^2s^2-q^2r^2)^2)\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$D \le 0$
since it is the negative of
the sum of squares.
For the quadratic to have a real root,
$D$ must be zero,
and, in this case,
there is one repeated real root.

Note that
if $D=0$
then
$p^2r^2=q^2s^2$
and
$p^2s^2=q^2r^2$.

You can work with this
to get various conditions
relating
$p, q, r, $ and $s$,
but this is enough
to answer your question.

Comment: absolutely nothing. The squaring makes the signs vanish.

Comment: Ah, I misread the question.

Answer (score 1):

$\triangle' = (2pqrs)^2 - (p^4+q^4)(r^4+s^4) = (2p^2q^2)(2r^2s^2) - (p^4+q^4)(r^4+s^4) \leq (p^4+q^4)(r^4+s^4) - (p^4+q^4)(r^4+s^4) = 0$. This says about the roots.

Comment: Sorry i do not understand how you got (p^4+q^4)(r^4+s^4) from (2p^2q^2)*(2r^2s^2)

Comment: @Mathbreaker: use: 2p^2q^2 < p^4 + q^4 and 2r^2s^2 < r^4 + s^4

Comment: But aren't they supposed to be equal instead of smaller/greater than the other, to give me real singular solution?

Comment: Take a look at my answer above where I derive an exact expression for the discriminant.